# How to get the color of a pixel in a Java applet to produce a map?

Tags: java, image, applet

I am working with a Java to create a small applet. I am interested if there is a way I can "scan" an image to get the color values of a certain pixel. I would prefer to not have to display the image on the screen, but if you find that is the only way, please tell me. I would ideally like to be able to have my applet scan an image file and create an image on the screen according to the image. Please try to keep the answers a little bit simple, as I am still getting used to all of the technical terms.

Thanks,
  ~Rane

What I have so far:

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class LoadGuideImage {

Applet applet;

public LoadGuideImage(Applet applet){
    this.applet = applet;
}

public String getPixelColor(String pathToImage, int Xpix, int Ypix){
    int redC = 0;
    int greenC = 0;
    int blueC = 0;

    //Get Pixel colors here and save to ints

    return redC + " " + greenC + " " + blueC;
}

}
```

Are you suggesting something like this 'the other guy'?:

```
        BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) getImage(pathToImage);

    System.out.println("Color: " + img.getRGB(3, 3));
```

getImage method:

```
    public Image getImage(String path) {

    Image img;
    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = applet.getDocumentBase();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    img = applet.getImage(url, path);

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried, please.

Comment: I have added what I have so far. It is not much because I wasn't sure in which direction I should head with this.

Comment: 1. Load your image. 2. Create a [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). 3. Draw your image onto it. 4. Use the BufferedImage's `.getRGB(x,y)` to get the pixel value

Comment: If I were to do this, I would have to display the image on the screen, right?

Comment: *"If I were to do this, I would have to display the image on the screen, right?"*  Wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice name by the way. So I was in the same position a while ago.

use this for your get image method, just tweak it and use it to benefit you:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    public BufferedImage load(String path){
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have a been making a game that uses individual pixels to load those pixels and then put tiles where certain pixels are located in the map. If you would like to take my code snippet from there let me know and ill hook you up :P

Comment: Thanks you! You have an interesting name as well. I have seen the 'ImageIO.read' appear often in my search of how to do what I am asking to do. I would use it, but Eclipse gives me an error stating 'ImageIO can not be resolved'. I copied your method above. I only removed the 'public class ImageLoader {' bit. (As well as the closing } at the end) Do you know why? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sorry. Please discard that. I was able to get Eclipse to recognize ImageIO. Thank you; you fixed the problem!